# WP_Query to include all posts from category and also include all private posts (private posts may not be in category that was included)

Tags: wordpress

I've been struggling to get this wp_query to work as i want it to.

I want to fetch all posts from category test and also fetch all posts flagged as private, the thing is the posts flagged as private may not be in the category test.

I cannot get this to work, i've tried several of queries without any luck, the latest one that i came closest to success is this one:

```
  $args = array(
  'post_status' => array('private, publish'),
  'relation' => 'OR', 
  'category_name' => 'test'
);
```

This one seem to only fetch posts that are in the test category, all posts that are private and outside the test category are not displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: not particularly sure why this would do any difference i get the same results with get_posts, i see all posts in category test, but none of the posts that are outside category test but flagged as private.

Comment: did you give the option uncategorized and test for displaying the posts?

Comment: uncategorized to fetch private posts outside the category test? the problem is the other private posts that are outside category test have other categories assigned to them.

Comment: No sandra then you have to include those categories too. Uncategories if posts is not assigned to other categories like test then it will be "uncategorized" category right as default